# How to run a weighted Cox regression model

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weighted, cox-regression

I'm trying to run a weighted Cox regression model but none of the resources I found were actually useful to figure out how to do that.

Basically, I just want to run the model specified below, but weighted.

```
coxph(Surv(df$outcome)~df$treatment)
```

Apparently the `coxphw` function is the way to do this, but I cannot figure out the necessary specifications to actually make that function run.

Answer (score 0):

The 'template' option of the coxphw determines which type of (weighted) estimation of Cox regression is requested. You can choose "AHR" for estimation of average HRs or "ARE" for estimation of average regression effects and "PH" for unweighted Cox proportional hazards regression. Check the ref manual for more details.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I was able to run the model using the "AHR" specification, but I fail to understand how that incorporates the inverse probability weights I calculated, which are represented by a variable I created (called "weights"). In other words, what does the "AHR" specification exactly do under the hood?